# Is there a simple, 2D, customizable-text, screensaver for Raspbian

Tags: linux

We've set up a Clock-in/Clock-out application interface for touch screen on a Raspberry Pi.  We'd like a screensaver that simply says, "Touch the screen to clock in/out."  The 3D gl xScreensaver is too hard for the ARM processor and so does not create a "smooth" motion for the text (plus it keeps processor use pegged and makes the processor quite hot).

Does anyone know of a simple text-crawler-type screensaver that simply moves the specified text (e.g. "Touch the screen to clock in/out.") across the screen on randomly selected lines...with no 3D special effects?